# Custom template rendering with *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a History component which holds an array of `HistoryEntries`.

`HistoryComponent` looks like:

```
 @Component({
 selector: 'history',
 template: `
    <div>         
       <historyEntry *ngFor='let entry of historyentries'></historyEntry>
    </div> `,
    directives : [HistoryEntryComponent]
 })
```

The HistoryComponent-class looks like:

```
export class HistoryComponent{
   public historyentries = [
                    new HistoryEntryComponent(1, "lalala"),
                    new HistoryEntryComponent(2, "xxxxx")
                    ];
}
```

Then I have a HistoryEntryComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'historyentry',
  template: `
    <div>
        <h1>ID: {{Id}} , Descr.: {{Description}}</h1>
    </div>
`
})
```

and a class:

```
export class HistoryEntryComponent {
   constructor(public Id : Number, public Description : string)
   {}
}
```

If I render that, nothings shows up. I have already used a `<li>` to display the id and description, which works like expected. But of course `HistoryEntry` itself could get very complicated and need its own logic etc. So there must be a way to render `<historyentry>` as given by a template, isn't it?

In WPF I would say `HistoryEntry` is a `UserControl` with its own `ViewModel` attached.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
@Component({
 selector: 'history',
 template: `
    <div>         
       <historyentry *ngFor='let entry of historyentries' [entry]="entry"></historyentry>
    </div> `,
    directives : [HistoryEntryComponent]
})
```

```
export class HistoryEntryComponent {
   @Input() entry:HistoryEntry; // or whatever type `entry` is
   constructor()
   {}
}
```

```
<h1>ID: {{entry?.Id}} , Descr.: {{entry?.Description}}</h1>
```

Comment: I get a "Can't bind to 'entry' since it isn't a known native property". The type of "entry" would be "HistoryEntryComponent", because that's what ngFor iterates. Although I like this solution much better than set "Id" and "Description" separately it's still weird. We tell Angular we want render <historyentry>-elements and iterate of historyentries why do we have to set the value of the iteration manually to the historyentry-element?

Comment: Just because the `*ngFor` is on the `<historyEntry>` element, doesn't mean data has to be related to `<historyEntry>`. The tag has to be `<historyentry>` instead of `<historyEntry>` or change the selector from `historyentry` to `historyEntry`. I copied this mistake from your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide id and description as input to the historyendcomponent

```
<historyEntry *ngFor='let entry of historyentries' [id]="entry.id" [description]="entry.description"></historyEntry>

export class HistoryEntryComponent {
   @Input id:number;
   @Inpur description:string;
   constructor(public Id : Number, public Description : string)
   {}
}
```

Comment: <historyEntry *ngFor='let entry of historyentries' [id]="entry.Id" [description]="entry.description"></historyEntry> doesn't compile while <historyEntry *ngFor='let entry of historyentries' [id]="entry.Id"> </historyEntry> does. Which is strange. But I also don't understand the solution. ngFor iterates of historyentries. So why do I have to set the properties again? What about private members?